# jsonwebtoken when do decode returns null for expired token

Tags: node.js, jwt, json-web-token

I am looking for a solution where I can get payload for the expired token. I am using jsonwebtoken.

```
var token = jwt.verify(data,secret_key, (err,tokendata)=>{
        console.log('1'+JSON.stringify(err));
        console.log('2'+jwt.decode(tokendata));
        console.log('3'+tokendata);
        console.log('4'+JSON.stringify(jwt.decode(token)));
        if(err) {
          if(err.name == 'TokenExpiredError') {
            console.log('here');
            var decode = jwt.decode(token);
            console.log(tokendata);
          } else {
            var result = {};
            var data = {'email' : email};
            result['isError'] = true;
            result['status']  = 403;
            result['message'] = 'Invalid accesstoken';
            result['data']    = jwt.decode(token);
            resolve(result);
          }
        } else {
          var decode = jwt.decode(token);
          resolve(decode);
        }
});
```

Can anyone suggest how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: I`m sorry, but your question is a bit vague? What exactly happens with your jwt? Please elaborate, it will increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: I want payload in Expired Token